# JavaScript 'Alert' Does NOT Pop Up My Success Message

Tags: javascript, html, forms, alert

Hello I'm just finishing up a website for a page I have been working on. I added an HTML Form that allows a user/reader to enter there 'full name', 'email' and a 'message'. I connected my form to "google sheet" via a 'API' import and attached it with my JS code. When the 'Send Message' button is clicked, if the input was sent successfully then the 'Alert' tab pops up with a successfully sent message string.

However instead I kept getting just a JSON on a separate page from my web page. Something that looks like

> ```
> {"result":"success","row":14}
> ```

I then checked over my JavaScript and I realized something was wrong though I don't understand how to fix it. This is the JavaScript

```js
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(Form) })
    .then(Response => alert("You have successfully submitted"))
    .catch(error => console.error("Error!", error.message))
})
```

The problem here is 'Response' it's declared but not read. How to fix this?

Comment: Nah, declared. but not read is not an issue. Most likely you clicked "prevent this page from creating additional popups" at some point. Be aware that alert is frowned upon for any serious use.

Comment: @seesharper how do I disable this?

Comment: It's not super clear from your question but are you saying that when you submit your form, a new tab opens and shows that JSON? If that's the case, it sounds like your _submit_ event listener isn't being applied to the correct `<form>`. Have you checked your browser console for errors?

Comment: @Kevan, hard-refresh the tab clears the effect of having clicked "prevent this page...". But I suggest you change the alert to a console.log temporarily to see if that gets hit.

Answer (score 1):

Hi everyone I figured out the problem/s. I did no reference the 'JavaScript' correctly in my HTML page and I also changed the name of the spreadsheet of which I did not apply to my form that is

`const form = document.forms['my-sheet']`

so when I fetched my scriptURL from the form it mapped to an unknown form. Also to note I only used the 'Alert' as an example to display some sort of feedback when the button was clicked. I am not using the 'Alert' function in my final draft of the project. This is what the corrected script looks like

```
<form name="your-sheet" id="contact" action="purchase.html" method="POST" autocomplete="off" target="_blank">

    const scriptURL = 'https://somerandomurl/google.com/morerandominfo/exec'
    const form = document.forms['your-sheet']
    
    form.addEventListener('submit', e=> {
    e.preventDefault()
    fetch(scriptURL, {
    method: 'POST'
    body: new FormData(form)})
    .then(response => alert("Successfuly submitted!"))
    .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))})
```

Also sorry if my formatting is messy still trying to understand how to format. The 'Crtl+k' just puts the grey tab in and the 6 backstrokes don't do anything either.